# Web-scraping: I only get 1/10 of the text I want (using BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage, and all the text I want is placed between `<p class="heading2">` and `More...`.

It works with the first batch of text, but just that one.

E.g. I get:

```
Info about grant 1
```

But on the website there's:

```
Info about grant 1 
Info about grant 2 
Info about grant 3 
etc.
```

Here's the code I'm using. I'm new to BeautifulSoup, so I hope someone can help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sheetsync
import urllib2, csv
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.asanet.org/funding/funding_and_grants.cfm').read()
def processData():
    url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.asanet.org/funding/funding_and_grants.cfm').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
    metaData = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"memberscontent"})
    authors = []
    for html in metaData:
            text = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).encode("utf-8").replace("Deadline", "DEADLINE").replace('\s+',' ').replace('\n+',' ').replace('\s+',' ')
            authors.append(text.split('<p class="heading2">')[1].split('More...')[0].strip()) # get Pos
            txt = 'grants.txt'
    with open(txt, 'ab') as out:
        out.writelines(authors)
processData()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rely on the `heading2` and get next two `p` tag [siblings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling): the first is deadline, the second is grant's text:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.asanet.org/funding/funding_and_grants.cfm'))

for heading in soup.select('div#memberscontent p.heading2'):
    deadline = heading.find_next_sibling('p')
    article = deadline.find_next_sibling('p') 

    print heading.get_text(strip=True)
    print deadline.get_text(strip=True)
    print article.get_text(strip=True)
    print "----"
```

Prints:

```
The Sydney S. Spivack Program in Applied Social Research and Social PolicyASA Congressional Fellowship
Deadline: February 15
The ASA encourages applications for its Congressional Fellowship. The Fellowship brings a PhD-level sociologist to Washington, DC, to work as a staff member on a congressional committee, in a congressional member office, or in a congressional agency (e.g., the Government Accountability Office). This intensive six-month experience reveals the intricacies of the policy making process to the sociological fellow, and shows the usefulness of sociological data and concepts to policy issues.  [More...]
----
Community Action Research Initiative (CARI Grants) The Sydney S. Spivack Program in Applied Social Research and Social Policy
Deadline:  February 15
To encourage sociologists to undertake community action projects that bring social science knowledge, methods, and expertise to bear in addressing community-identified issues and concerns, ASA administers competitive CARI awards. Grant applications are encouraged from sociologists seeking to work with community organizations, local public interest groups, or community action projects. Appointments will run for the duration of the project, whether the activity is to be undertaken during the year, in the summer, or for other time-spans.   [More...]
----
Fund for the Advancement of the Discipline
Deadlines:  June 15 | December 15
The American Sociological Association invites submissions by PhD sociologists for the Fund for the Advancement of the Discipline (FAD) awards. Supported by the American Sociological Association through a matching grant from the National Science Foundation, the goal of this project is to nurture the development of scientific knowledge by funding small, groundbreaking research initiatives and other important scientific research activities such as conferences. FAD awards provide scholars with small grants ($7,000 maximum) for innovative research that has the potential for challenging the discipline, stimulating new lines of research, and creating new networks of scientific collaboration. The award is intended to provide opportunities for substantive and methodological breakthroughs, broaden the dissemination of scientific knowledge, and provide leverage for acquisition of additional research funds.  [More...]
----
...
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working great, but the grant titles are missing? The first text after heading2!

Comment: Great, this is very helpful and something I can learn a lot from. Thank you!